# how to make datatables background image clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using datatables wherein for a particular column I need the set background image as clickable.

I am unable to put it together. I can do it for the text but can figure out how it needs to be done for the backgorund image. Can anyone suggest.

here is my javascript->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myArray=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("populateDT").innerHTML);
        $('#example').dataTable
        (
            {
                "sScrollY": "500px",
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                 aaData: myArray,

                "aoColumns":
                    [
                        { "mData": "Id"},
                        { "mData": "Label"},
                        { "mData": "CT"},
                        { "mData": "data"},
                        { "mData": "Updated"},
                        { "sClass": "center", "mData":"", "sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="editor_save">"getimage"</a> '},
                        { "sClass": "editimage", "mData":"","sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="editor_save">this</a> ' },
                        { "sClass": "deleteimage", "mData":""}
                    ]
            } );
    });
```

Following is my HTML

```
<table class="display" id="example" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="addedit.jsp">Add Code Edit</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Import</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Export</a></li>
</ul>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>CT</th>
    <th>data</th>
    <th>UpdatedAt</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="getimage"></td>
    <td class="editimage"></td>
    <td class="deleteimage"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the getimage, editimage and deleteimage as clickable. 
I am trying to understand this link http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/envelope_inline.html
but need some help. appreciate it. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/bujfp/

Comment: You don't want the background-image to be clickable, you want the td element to be clickable. background-image is only a css style, is not an element you can click on. can you make a jsFiddle? Give also your CSS.

Comment: yes your right the td element should be clickable, but how to achieve that. I dont know if my jsfiddle is helpful. If you could provide an example that should be enough. @Antonis

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will change the  background color:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //handle the click
    $('td',this).click(function() {
        $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //handle the click
    $('td',this).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass( "panama-red" );
    });
});
```

I'd recommend using .addClass instead of .css.

Comment: thanks for the code . But I dont know, its not working for me.,